# How to check that vsprintf has the correct number of arguments before running

Tags: php, regex, printf

I'm trying to use vsprintf() to output a formatted string, but I need to validate that I have the correct number of arguments before running it to prevent "Too few arguments" errors.

In essence I think what I need is a regex to count the number of type specifiers, but I'm pretty useless when it comes to regex and I couldn't fund it anywhere so I thought I'd give SO a go. :)

Unless you can think of a better way this method is along the lines of what I want.

```
function __insertVars($string, $vars = array()) {

    $regex = '';
    $total_req = count(preg_match($regex, $string));

    if($total_req === count($vars)) {
        return vsprintf($string, $vars);
    }

}
```

Please tell me if you can think of a simpler way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your solution is the only way to more or less reliably tell how many arguments are in the string.

Here is the regular expression I came up with, use it with `preg_match_all()`:

```
%[-+]?(?:[ 0]|['].)?[a]?\d*(?:[.]\d*)?[%bcdeEufFgGosxX]
```

Based upon [`sprintf()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php). Should be compatible with **PHP 4.0.6+ / 5**.

---

**EDIT** - A slightly more compact version:

```
%[-+]?(?:[ 0]|'.)?a?\d*(?:\.\d*)?[%bcdeEufFgGosxX]
```

Also, take advantage of the `func_get_args()` and `func_num_args()` functions in your code.

---

**EDIT:** - Updated to support positional/swapping arguments (*not tested*):

```
function validatePrintf($format, $arguments)
{
    if (preg_match_all("~%(?:(\d+)[$])?[-+]?(?:[ 0]|['].)?(?:[-]?\d+)?(?:[.]\d+)?[%bcdeEufFgGosxX]~", $format, $expected) > 0)
    {
        $expected = intval(max($expected[1], count(array_unique($expected[1]))));

        if (count((array) $arguments) >= $expected)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

var_dump(validatePrintf('The %2$s contains %1$d monkeys', array(5, 'tree')));
```

Comment: But what if the function is something like `vsprintf(format, args)` when `format = '%3$s'`?

Comment: @lmojzis: Use the regular expression I provided with `$format`?

Comment: Okay, let me explain. Your `args` is `array('a','b')` and `format` is `'%3$s'` well then clearly you want to get the third key of `args` but your `count(args)` is `int(2)`, however it comes throught because number of matches is `int(1)` and `(int(1)<=int(2)) == true`

Comment: @lmojzis: Ah, right... Well, I don't think that that can't be done with regexes alone, but if you find a solution let me know.

Comment: You could, however, search for the highest number in parameters, couldn't you?

Comment: @lmojzis: Yeah, check my update. I'm not sure if there are any bugs there tho.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's very easy, because it returns FALSE value if something wrong.
You can check like this:

```
if (vsprintf($string, $wrongArray) === false) {
    // vsprintf has wrong number of arguments
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me if (vsprintf('test is a %s') === false) {} raises an error: Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: vsprintf() expects exactly 2 arguments

Answer (score 0):

I used Alix Axel answer and created universal function.

We have a `$countArgs` (from function parameters) and `$countVariables` (from `$format` like `%s`).

For example:

```
$object->format('Hello, %s!', ['Foo']); // $countArgs = 1, $countVariables = 1;
```

Print: Hello, Foo!

```
$object->format('Hello, %s! How are you, %s?', ['Bar']); // $countArgs = 1, $countVariables = 2;
```

Print: Error.

Function:

```
public static function format($format, array $args)
{
    $pattern = "~%(?:(\d+)[$])?[-+]?(?:[ 0]|['].)?(?:[-]?\d+)?(?:[.]\d+)?[%bcdeEufFgGosxX]~";

    $countArgs = count($args);
    preg_match_all($pattern, $format, $expected);
    $countVariables = isset($expected[0]) ? count($expected[0]) : 0;

    if ($countArgs !== $countVariables) {
        throw new \Exception('The number of arguments in the string does not match the number of arguments in a template.');
    } else {
        return $countArgs > 1 ? vsprintf($format, $args) : sprintf($format, reset($args));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add more of an explanation?

Comment: @Shawn yes, I added a comments.

Comment: I believe `vsprintf()` allows for `%%` to represent a single `%`? I don't think this regex allows for that